# Why can I select the view definition but not the view itself, despite correct permissions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, permissions, view

I'm having a strange issue on PostgreSQL 9.0.1 on Windows Server 2003 SP2.

I connect as a superuser and then SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION to user 
"X" who is a member of group role "extranet_user" which inherits 
membership from group role "user".  "X", "extranet_user", and even 
"user" are all INHERIT.

I have the following view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW page_startup AS 
 SELECT contact.name, contact.nickname, COALESCE( 
        CASE 
            WHEN has_table_privilege('mandate'::text, 'select'::text) 
THEN ( SELECT false AS bool 
               FROM mandate 
       NATURAL JOIN task 
         WHERE task.waiting_for = "session_user"()::text::integer AND 
task.deadline < now() 
        LIMIT 1) 
            ELSE NULL::boolean 
        END, true) AS no_mandates 
   FROM contact 
  WHERE contact.id = "session_user"()::text::integer; 
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE page_startup TO "user";
```

If I run this:

```
set session authorization "X"; 
select pg_has_role('user','member')
```

I get `'t'` as a result.  Also, if I run this (just copying the 
definition of the view):

```
set session authorization "X"; 
 SELECT contact.name, contact.nickname, COALESCE( 
        CASE 
            WHEN has_table_privilege('mandate'::text, 'select'::text) 
THEN ( SELECT false AS bool 
               FROM mandate 
       NATURAL JOIN task 
         WHERE task.waiting_for = "session_user"()::text::integer AND 
task.deadline < now() 
        LIMIT 1) 
            ELSE NULL::boolean 
        END, true) AS no_mandates 
   FROM contact 
  WHERE contact.id = "session_user"()::text::integer;
```

I get the single row of data I'm looking for.

However, if I try to use the view instead of copying its definition:

```
set session authorization "X"; 
select * from page_startup
```

I get the following:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation page_startup 
********** Error ********** 
ERROR: permission denied for relation page_startup 
SQL state: 42501
```

Strange, no?  Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out restarting pgAdminIII somehow fixed it.  I had, at some point after first encountering this error, changed the permissions of extranet_user to inherit, and the results had not changed.  This morning I started up pgAdminIII, copied the code from this post, and it worked.